# Track state of HTTP request and add / remove spinner on request events firing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a button that behaves as `Redirect to Page in this Application`. Referenced page responds with a server-generated file that is being then downloaded on the client side.

I don't know how it all works, it was developed by other member of our team. But I need to handle start of the request, when the file is requested, and it's end, when it's ready to be downloaded, and IE11 prompts a download dialog box.

I need to create a spinner, wait for downloading to be ready and remove the spinner.

jQuery code I've written:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(apex.util.showSpinner($("#myButtonParentRegion")));
$(document).ajaxComplete($("#myButtonParentRegion .spinnerContainer").remove());
```

**THE PROBLEM:** But this code doesn't work. (Why?) I can't do anything with AJAX call directly, it is being handled by a whole different code written by another developer. But all I need is to listen for events and draw / remove a spinner. How?

---

**UPDATE:** In my case it doesn't work because it was not an AJAX request, but a regular HTTP request with item values that opens a page with a report region which returns a CSV file with a table on item value condition.

I managed to add spinner with the following code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    apex.util.showSpinner($("#myButtonParentRegion"));
});
```

**THE NEW PROBLEM:** But I can't remove it, `unload` event doesn't work for some reason. How to remove the spinner?

Comment: *"Is that correct syntax"* ... No. Suggest you read the ajaxStart and ajaxComplete documentation in the jQuery API

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it's emperical behaviour you want to track, then the browser console gives you pretty good information about every request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, btw, it helped with debug. Know that I can check the network activity, but forgot at the time.